# Wordpress and its features

Tags: php, ajax, database, wordpress

I have just started working with wordpress. I am hoping to ask this question while still staying in compliance of this site. I will be looking for fact not discussion or suggestions.

I get a little confused about what is a wordpress features and what is a feature of a theme.

For example if something is a feature of wordpress is post. You can call a wordpress api function and this will print out data that wordpress provides. But something like a slider and the images contained is a feature of the theme..(for the most part. unless it's post pics)

I just wanted to get a complete knowledge or summary of the features of wordpress.

The ability to print out the post is one feature

The ability to paginate post is this also a feature of something that the theme need to provide. I believe the theme would have to provide the buttons but wordpress would do the pagination. 
The reason i Assume this is because a php framework like laravel does suppost this feature just wondering if this is also true here.

If it does support pagination when you request more from an ajax call is this handled by your own function in your function.php or would you need to make a seperate url.
Normal framework you would do a separate url but doesn't seem liek wordpress would give you this feature.

For the Featured post is this something that is a part of wordpress that would track your most recent post and display that list of feature post or is this something the theme developer would have to implement them self.

Wordpress has a database does the theme developer has access to this database to create there own table and navigate the database. This seems like it should be doable because it is just plain php at times so nothing too fancy. Do people do this. How would they avoid conflicting table names and things of that nature.

"sigh really hate mysqlconnect and PDO tickles my interest but not really".

If there is some wordpress guru out there thanks for all the help and the clarification. 
Hopefully this will full help other realize what exactly is the power of WordPress and what is the power of a plugin or a theme.

Thank for all the help.

Comment: I am asking if i am correct with what i am saying. I want to be able to differentiate between what is a feature of wordpress or what would actually be the feature of a theme. Because when i see alot of the other theme i get confused as to what is a wordpress feature and what is a theme feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is a powerful platform that can be easily built upon. For one of your examples, WordPress has a feature of pagination, however theme developers need to IMPLEMENT that feature to make it available to the end-user. Some theme developers choose not to implement the feature for whatever reason.

featured posts is another "feature" that can be implemented in many different ways, usually by a theme developer. What is "featured" for one person may be different for another.

Lastly, theme developer AND plugin developers have the ability to create tables and use them for their own purposes. Developers would have to try to use a unique naming convention to try to prevent naming collisions, but not all do.

WordPress has a list of features here: http://wordpress.org/about/features/

Comment: hey thanks this is a very good answer i rated up. But didn't mark as the final asnswer yet just incase there are some more things than can be added to futher distinguish theme feature from vanilla wordpress features that need to be implemented